# Como aplicar o complemento de dois em uma string hex em c#?

Tags: c#

Preciso de ajuda para converter uma string hex em uma string hex aplicando complemento de dois.

Exemplo: 0x00FEB5AB → 0x00014A55

Meu hex. 00FF17DB → ? (representa uma latitude negativa)

e 00FCFF75 → ? (representa uma longitude negativa)

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simples poderá ser calcular o [complemento para 1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_n%C3%BAmeros_com_sinal#Complemento_para_um) e somar 1 como descrito na entrada [Complemento para dois](https://pt.Wikip%C3%A9dia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois) da wikipedia.

Digo que é uma forma simples porque é fácil calcular o *complemento de 1*, bastando para isso aplicar a operação *bitwise NOT* ao valor:

```
const string valor = "00FEB5AB";
//Converte para inteiro
uint valorInteiro = Convert.ToUInt32(valor, 16);
//Aplica o bitwise NOT e soma 1
uint complemento = ~valorInteiro + 1;
//Converte para string no formato hexadecimal
string complementoHex = string.Format("{0:X}", complemento);
```

Note que o valor calculado é "FF014A55" e não "00014A55" como você diz,
porque o resultado é calculado considerando a amplitude(número de bytes) do *input*.

Pelo que me foi dado a perceber as calculadoras existentes na net só consideram os bytes significativos, fazendo o cálculo truncando os bytes não significativos(00's à esquerda).

Usando o código acima, o método seguinte permite fazer o cálculo das duas formas:

```
public string ComputeTwosComplement(string hexValue, bool areAllBytesSignificant)
{
    const int maxNumberOfBytes = 8;
    int lenght = hexValue.Length;

    //Não permite mais de 64bits
    if (lenght > maxNumberOfBytes*2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(hexValue);

    //Converte hexadecimal para long
    ulong intValue = Convert.ToUInt64(hexValue, 16);

    //Calcula o complemento para 2
    ulong complement = (~intValue + 1);

    //Converte para hexadecimal
    string twosComplement = string.Format("{0:X16}", complement);

    if (areAllBytesSignificant)
    {
        //Ajusta para o mesmo número de bytes do valor passado
        twosComplement = twosComplement.Substring(maxNumberOfBytes*2 - lenght);
    }
    else
    {
        //Representação hexadecimal do valor passado sem 00's à esquerda
        string significantBytes = string.Format("{0:X}", intValue);
        //Ajusta para o número de bytes significativos do valor passado
        twosComplement = twosComplement.Substring(maxNumberOfBytes*2 - significantBytes.Length);
    }
    return twosComplement;
}
```

Para manter a amplitude e obter "FF014A55" use:

```
ComputeTwosComplement("00FEB5AB", true);
```

Para ajustar a amplitude e obter "014A55" use:

```
ComputeTwosComplement("00FEB5AB", false);
```

Note que se o valor passado não tiver 00's à esquerda("FEB5AB") é indiferente passar `true` ou `false`, o resultado é sempre "014A55".

Comment: Usei esse código.   
`string hexPosition = "00FF17DB";
uint intHexPosition = Convert.ToUInt32(hexPosition, 16);
uint twosComp = ~intHexPosition + 1;
hexPosition = string.Format("{0:X}", twosComp);`  

Mas me retorna FF00E825 o correto seria E825 pq?

Comment: Eu já tinha chamado a atenção para esse facto na resposta. Julgo que poderá ter haver com o facto de se estar a usar 32bits no cálculo. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Eu usei um conversor online e bateu certinho porem eu passei os valores em hex depois converti em bin logo em seguida apliquei o complemento de 2 e depois converti de volta pra hex.
`00FF17DB -> 111111110001011111011011 -> 2C -> 000000001110100000100101 - > E825.`

Comment: Confirme por favor se para 0x00FEB5AB é 0x00014A55 ou é 0x00004A55

Comment: Correto para o valor hex "00FF17DB". Porém o valor hex "00FCFF75" retornar incorreto (0000008B). O valor esperado para "00FCFF75" seria FF03008B.

Comment: 00FEB5AB = 00004A55

Comment: Se para o valor "00FCFF75" é "FF03008B" então a versão inicial está certa. Não compreendo porque umas vezes dá certo outras não.

Comment: Vou reverter para a versão inicial.

Comment: Desculpe o valor para "00FCFF75" = 3008B porém retorna 0000008B.  
O valor "00FF17DB" está correto E825. Também não entendi o porque funcionar para "00FF17DB" e não funcionar para  "00FCFF75". =/

Comment: 0x0F7EF73D → 0x008108C3 (Correto)
Aplicando o segundo exemplo retorna 000008C3 (?)
Manual do protocolo pagina 73 diz 32bits.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82vmwUnG1x8bXZrbUw3ZTZnTjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ramaral o problema está só dependendo do numero de bytes usados. Se usasse 3 bytes no 1o valor, daria certo. Eu acho que a pergunta está com problemas nesse sentido, é necessário saber o comprimento certo do valor antes de aplicar o complemento AA -> 56, 00AA -> FF56, etc. - Para complemento, especificar o tamanho é fundamental.

Comment: @Baco Se entendi o seu comentário o resultado terá de ser truncado de forma a ter o mesmo comprimento do input não considerando os pares de zeros à esquerda(número de bytes significativos): input = 00AA => --AA, comprimento = 2, resultado 56. Isto claro para ir de encontro ao que o AP pede.

Comment: Pensei em truncar mas fiquei com receio. Vou fazer alguns testes com outros dados.
Nesse link retorna perfeitamente.(http://www.hobbyprojects.com/calculators/binary_decimal_hex_converter.html)

Comment: Perfeito! Fico muito grato.