# Dúvida com soma de binários sinalizados

Tags: matemática, ciência-da-computação, binary

Estou estudando operações com números binários sinalizados e me surgiu uma dúvida que gostaria que vocês me esclarecessem:

ao somar dois números com 6 bits sendo 001111(+15) e 010110(+22) obtive o resultado 100101(-5) sendo que o correto seria 0100101(+37).

O que quero saber é se essa adição do 0 na frente é considerada overflow(já que estoura os 6 bits) ou não tem importância alguma?

Comment: `100101` é 37 não considerando o primeiro bit como sinal. Qual o formato de negativos que está a considerar ? Complemento de 2 ?

Comment: @Isac, para obter -5, deve ser um complemento pouco usual para ULAs. Deve ser simplesmente desconsiderar o bit de sinal, o resto dando o módulo do número

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pois, é porque existem algumas representações diferentes de binário, logo é preciso saber como ele estava a considerar. O mais comum é mesmo complemento de 2 como deu na resposta, mas duvido que seja o que o AP está a considerar

Comment: @Isac, eu conheço complemento de 2, complemento de 1 (que permite a existência do -0) e essa do sinal magnitude. Acho que eu poderia incrementar minha resposta com esses esquemas de numeração. Você está certo quanto a precisar levar em consideração qual esquema está sendo usado. Mas a verdade é que estou com preguiça de incrementar a resposta agora, se você puder colocar uma resposta com essas peculiaridades, seria ótimo

Comment: @naosei, achas que ainda tem algo sobrando que eu possa tratar na resposta? Vi que gostaste dela, queria saber se poderia deixar ainda mais completa

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tá ótimo, esclareceu minha dúvida, obrigado

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade, o resultado obtido é o certo ([assumindo complemento de 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248453/d%C3%BAvida-com-soma-de-bin%C3%A1rios-sinalizados#comment509293_248453)
, como percebido pelo [@Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82711/isac)). Mas não é `-5`, e sim `-27`. Mas se você assumir sinal magnitude (veja mais abaixo), o binário que você obteve seria `-5` mesmo, mas eu creio que não se faz soma desse jeito na representação sinal magnitude, portanto sou levado a crer que você está a usar complemento de 2.

Estamos em um mundo de 6 bits. Esse mundo consegue representar até um máximo de 64 números distintos. Se não houvesse sinal, esses números variariam de 0 a 63. Como há sinal, no complemento de 2 os números representados são 0 a 31, -32 a -1.

Se você estivesse em um mundo de bitagem variável, aí ocorreria a presença de um bit extra só para indicar que não é um número negativo, mas não é o caso.

Somar dois positivos e obter um negativo na minha lembrança não é um *overflow*. *Overflow* seria somar de tal modo que seriam necessários 7 bits independente de sinal para representar a soma obtida. Ou seja, seria o sexagésimo quinto número, estourando a capacidade dos 6 bits de representação. Isso ocorre com `-1 + 1`.

Alguns números extremos e interessantes com 6 bits:

```
0   : 000 000
1   : 000 001
31  : 011 111
-32 : 100 000
-1  : 111 111
```

Algumas operações:

```
1 + -1 = 0
  000 001 +
  111 111 
  -------
  000 000 (1 de overflow)


15 + 22 = -27
  001 111 +
  010 110
  -------
  100 101

31 + -32 = -1
  011 111 +
  100 000
  -------
  111 111
```

## Notações binárias com sinal

Existem 5 principais notações para números binários com sinal:

1. Usar um sinal explícito, como na base decimal; porém isso implica que não é possível representar números binários com apenas dois símbolos do alfabeto numérico (a base 10 utiliza-se de 11 símbolos para representar inteiros positivos e negativos, 12 se contar o separador decimal e números quebrados)
2. Complemento de 2, modo mais usado por ser de aritmética extremamente simples para o processador/para a ULA
3. Complemento de 1, só conheço para fins acadêmicos
4. Sinal magnitude, onde o bit de sinal é totalmente independente dos bits de magnitude
5. "Valor deslocado", onde se considera inicialmente que o número não tem sinal e então subtrai por um "deslocamento", usado para calcular o expoente de pontos flutuantes

   > não achei nome melhor; lendo o [artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754?wprov=sfti1) achei o termo *bias* como sendo o que chamei de "deslocamento", mas não entendi qual seria o nome oficial do esquema de representação numérica

### Sinal explícito

Não muito usual para processadores. Muito mais comum para representar números negativos em outras bases, ou com números sem bitagem fixa:

```
101    : +5 em decimal
-101   : -5 em decimal
-10001 : -17 em decimal
10001  : +17 em decimal
```

Como lado negativo, exige a existência de um terceiro símbolo, o que o torna pouco atrativo para computadores que trabalham com dígitos binários. Sem falar que mesmo com dígitos trinários seria um grande desperdício de espaço...

### Complemento de 2

É o esquema mais usado pelas ULAs mundo a fora devido à sua simplicidade de manuseio. Não há diferença entre somar um número negativo nessa base com outro positivo. Ou vice-versa. Ou dois positivos. Ou dois negativos. A lógica de soma é idêntica, não precisa de nenhum circuito complementar nem de algoritmo de soma diferenciado quando se considera números negativos.

> Veja [esta resposta do @ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109374/64969) ensinando a calcular o complemento de 2

Esse esquema foi concebido de tal sorte que a soma de um número com o seu negativo seja sempre uma string de zeros (com um *overflow* resultante da operação).

Devido a suas características inerentes, existe um número negativo a mais do que positivos. Mas esse número negativo somado a ele mesmo resulta em zero. Para `n` bits, o maior número negativo em termos de magnitude é `-2^(n-1)`, portanto em 6 bits é -32, em 8 bits é -128.

### Complemento de 1

Esse esquema numérico foi elaborado como a simples negação do número positivo. Uma simples negação bit-a-bit de número gera seu complemento de 1. Isso implica na existência de `+0` e `-0`. Isso também implica que a quantidade de números positivos e negativos sejam idênticas. Então, para `n` bits, o maior número negativo em termos de magnitude é `-2^(n-1) +1`, portanto em 6 bits é -31, em 8 bits é -127.

> Veja [esta resposta do @ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109374/64969) ensinando a calcular o complemento de 1

Eu particularmente não conheço nenhuma utilidade prática para representação de números assim.

### Sinal magnitude

A ideia desse esquema é bem simples, inclusive é usado (grosso modo) em números flutuantes: o primeiro bit indica sinal, os outros bits são a magnitude do número. Isso implica as mesmas observações que eu coloquei acima para complemento de 1:

- existência de `+0 != -0`
- mesma quantidade de números positivos e negativos
- mesmos limites para números positivos e negativos

Além dessa ideia ser usada para números flutuantes, e talvez utilizada para representar abstrações numéricas maiores (como de repente alguma implementação de `BigInteger` do Java usar um bit de sinal), não conheço muitas utilidades dessa representação.

### "Valor deslocado"

Esse esquema de representação de números é bem simples. Imagina que eu começo do -15. Tudo que eu informo depois é o quão longe está desse valor base de deslocamento. O número que eu informo é um inteiro positivo.

Um outro modo de ver é: o número informado não tem sinal, mas depois de lê-lo, eu o desloco -15.

Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte número, de 5 bits:

```
11010
```

Se eu fosse ler esse número como sendo um número convencional sem sinal, eu valeria 2+8+16=26. Porém, ele está na verdade deslocado 15 casas, então o valor que devo considerar é 26-15=11.

Já para esse valor:

```
00101
```

Que valeria 5 lendo como se fosse um número convencional, é lido como 5-15=-10.

Essa notação de "valor deslocado" é usado para calcular qual o expoente usado no [formato de ponto flutuante IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754?wprov=sfti1). Esse deslocamento de -15 é o utilizado pelo formato de [meia precisão IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format?wprov=sfti1), conhecido oficialmente no jargão da IEEE 754-2008 como `binary16`.

---

Leitura adicional:

- [Essa pergunta no SESE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239036/how-are-negative-signed-values-stored) (pegue [desse comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248104/modificadores-int-unsigned-e-signed-na-linguagem-c/248108#comment508720_248108) do [@PabloAlmeida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26404/pablo-almeida))