# Como obter a representação de um número inteiro positivo em binário, usando recursão?

Tags: c, recursão, números-binários

Procurei por vários sites, e em nenhum eu consegui entender como fazer um código de conversão usando recursão de um inteiro positivo para binário.

Eu conheço que existe a função `itoa` porém o desafio do exercício é fazer de maneira recursiva.

Uma ideia de laço que eu tenho que pode ser possível

```
memset(&binario,NULL,10);
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
   quoc = dividendo / 2;
   resto = dividendo % 2;
   if (resto == 1) {
      binario[i] = '1';
   }
   dividendo = quoc;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109260/64969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para números positivos, o que podemos fazer é divisões sucessivas por dois e escrever o módulo 2 (ou `num & 1` para deixar explícito que se quer o bit) na posição adequada para isso.

Uma recursão interessante para fazer isso, escrevendo em *big-endian*, envolve retornar a posição para escrever o próximo caracter desejado e, na base da recursão, colocar o terminador de string `'\0'`, passando a posição atual da string como parâmetro. Eu particularmente faria isso retornando o endereço de memória, ou através de uma estrutura. Também faria uma função pública para fazer a chamada e essa, por sua vez, se preocuparia em fazer a chamada recursiva e colocar o `'\0'`.

```c
char* __private_to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return print_here;
  }
  print_here = __private_to_binary_representation(n >> 1, print_here);
  (*print_here) = (n & 1) + '0';
  return print_here + 1;
}

char* to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {
  int is_negative = n < 0? 1: 0;
  // primeiro, preencho o valor absoluto do número, então o primeiro bit sempre será 0
  char* null_terminator_pos = __private_to_binary_representation(abs(n), print_here + 1, 0);
  print_here[0] = '0';

  // garantindo o final da string
  (*null_terminator_pos) = '\0';

  if (is_negative) {
    char* bit_check;
    int bit1_found = 0;
    for (bit_check = null_terminator_pos - 1; bit_check >= print_here; bit_check--) {
      // troca os bits na representação de complemento de 2
      if (bit1_found) {
        (*bit_check) = (*bit_check) == '1'? '0': '1';
      } else if ((*bit_check) == '1') {
        bit1_found = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return print_here;
}
```

Exemplo de como chamar:

```c
char buff[100];
printf("to_binary_representation(%d), %s\n", 0, to_binary_representation(0, buff));
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/oasA9A).

Apoveitei e imprimi também números negativos em complemento de 2.

## Explicação dos números negativos

Ok, eu sei, os números negativos foram um extra. Mas eles são fáceis de explicar e são bem interessantes.

Conforme eu mencionei, estou usando a notação complemento de 2. Existem [outras possibilidades de notação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248464/64969), porém a mais usual realmente é complemento de 2.

[Essa resposta do @ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109374/64969) explica como obter um número em complemento de 2:

> Uma forma simples poderá ser calcular o [complemento para 1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_n%C3%BAmeros_com_sinal#Complemento_para_um) e somar 1 como descrito na entrada [Complemento para dois](https://pt.Wikip%C3%A9dia.org/wiki/Complemento_para_dois) da wikipedia.
>
> Digo que é uma forma simples porque é fácil calcular o *complemento de 1*, bastando para isso aplicar a operação *bitwise NOT* ao valor

Então, vamos lá. Peguemos um número qualquer em binário. Por exemplo, 5, representado em 8 bits:

> ```c
> 00000101
> ```

O complemento de 1 é o *bitwise NOT* do valor:

> ```c
> 11111010
> ```

Então, somamos 1 ao resultado final, obtendo assim o complemento de 2:

> ```c
> 11111011
> ```

Fazendo para 6, 7, 10 e 32, em um passo único

> 6:
>
> ```c
> 00000110
> 11111001
> 11111010
> ```
>
> 7:
>
> ```c
> 00000111
> 11111000
> 11111001
> ```
>
> 10:
>
> ```c
> 00001010
> 11110101
> 11110110
> ```
>
> 32:
>
> ```c
> 00100000
> 11011111
> 11100000
> ```

Notou que dá para fazer em um salto só, sem precisar fazer duas operações? Basta seguir o seguinte algoritmo:

1. percorra da direita para a esquerda
2. você começa no estado `bit1_not_found`
3. depois de ler um bit, você move uma posição para a esquerda
4. enquanto você está no estado `bit1_not_found`, repita o bit que foi lido na saída;
   se você leu `0`, coloque `0`, se você leu `1`, coloque `1`
5. enquanto você está no estado `bit1_found`, inverta o bit que foi lido na saída;
   se você leu `0`, coloque `1`, se você leu `1`, coloque `0`
6. se você leu o caracter `1` e está no estado `bit1_not_found`, mude seu estado para `bit1_found` (o caracter impresso continua o mesmo, só no próximo que será alterado)

Isso pode ser representado no seguinte [autômato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260864/64969):

[image: autômato do algoritmo acima]

> Nas ligações, o que temos uma notação estilo `X/Y`. Isso quer dizer que ao ler o caracter `X`, vai ser impresso o caracter `Y` e o estado será alterado para o que está na ponta da seta.
>
> Para o caso de duas transições contendo os mesmos estados de entrada e saída, foi representado colocando `;` para separar as entradas e saídas, como em `0/1 ; 1/0`.

Mas por que isso funciona?

Bem, em número pares, temos que a negação terminará com vários 1s, e a sequência de 1s se seguirá até a posição onde está o primeiro bit ligado do número original, que será trocado por 0. Então, temos que um número par e sua negação sempre serão do seguinte formato:

```c
    sequência de n 0s e um 1 no final
    _|_
   /   \
xxx10000
yyy01111
   \___/
     |
    sequência de n 1s e um 0 no final
```

O que acontece ao incrementar esse número? Bem, ele fará o *carry* nos `n` números da sequência e, na posição `n+1` da direita para a esquerda, o *carry* não será mais propagado. Então, qualquer que seja o número sendo incrementado, o seguinte vale:

```c
yyy01111
      +1
--------
yyy10000
```

Agora, comparemos o número original ao complemento de 2:

```c
xxx10000
yyy10000
```

Apenas os bits a esquerda do 1 são modificados. Todos os outros permanecem intactos.

A demonstração para o ímpar segue o mesmo pensamento, sendo que logo no primeiro dígito não há *carry*:

```c
    xxx1
    yyy0
```

```c
    yyy0
      +1
    ----
    yyy1
```

```c
    xxx1
    yyy1
```

O autômato está implementado neste trecho de código:

```c
// char* to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {

char* bit_check;
int bit1_found = 0;
for (bit_check = null_terminator_pos - 1; bit_check >= print_here; bit_check--) {
  // troca os bits na representação de complemento de 2
  if (bit1_found) {
    (*bit_check) = (*bit_check) == '1'? '0': '1';
  } else if ((*bit_check) == '1') {
    bit1_found = 1;
  }
}
```

## Sobre big-endian

A notação [big-endian](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50457/64969), é o modo como lemos números indo-arábicos em português: os bits mais significantes ficam no começo (a esquerda). Como a priori não sabemos quantos bits serão necessários, para imprimir do modo legível em português, eu deixo para escrever após detectar quantos bits são necessários para escrever o número. Então, o primeiro caracter a ser escrito será o menos significativo, na última posição da string.

A detecção de que se chegou no último caracter (ie, não precisa de nenhuma informação adicional) é:

```c
// char* __private_to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {

if (n == 0) {
  return print_here;
}
```

## Identificando os bits

A única posição garantida que eu posso verificar o bit é a menos significativa. Faço isso usando `(n & 1)`, a operação *bitwise* que vai retornar 1 ou 0, pois os bits mais significativos são zerados pelo segundo operando. Então, a representação é `'1'` para quando `(n & 1)` for verdade e `'0'` para o caso contrário.

Por sinal, quando é verdade, `(n & 1)` retorna 1, e retorna 0 caso contrário. Devido ao posicionamento da tabela ASCII, `'0' + 1` vai resultar em `'1'`, já `'0' + 0` continuará `'0'`.

Isso é identificado nesse trecho:

```c
//char* __private_to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {

(n & 1) + '0';
```

Para ficar sempre diminuindo o número a cada chamada recursiva, para pegar o próximo bit, fazemos a chamada recursiva deslocando o número 1 bit para a direita:

```c
n >> 1
```

Isso é equivalente a pegar a divisão inteira do número por 2 (descartando eventual resto), mas quis deixar mais claro que a minha intenção é tratar de deslocamento de bits.

## A posição de impressão

O dado mais significativo deve ser impresso na posição mais a esquerda. A identificação que chegou no número mais significativo é logo após identificar que acabou o número. Como estou imprimindo com sinal, eu também faço o *shift* para manter o bit de sinal intacto.

Por conta disso posição de impressão é passada intacta para o nível seguinte da iteração. Ao chegar o momento de retornar da iteração, deve ser passado ao nível anterior qual a posição que ele deve imprimir. No caso base da recursão, quando não há mais nada a ser impresso, retorna a posição de impressão inicial. Para todos os outros casos, retorna a posição logo a seguir, uma posição a direita.

O retorno se dá usando aritmética de ponteiros. Um espaço adiante é `ponteiro + 1`. Para escrever na posição do ponteiro, basta fazer `*ponteiro = valor` ou `ponteiro[0] = valor`. Eu preferi a primeira maneira para tornar mais claro que estou tratando de manipulação de ponteiros, já que a segunda forma, com índice, tem uma semântica agregada de vetor, o que não desejo.

Isso se encontra nesse trecho de código:

```c
char* __private_to_binary_representation(int n, char* print_here) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return print_here;
  }
  print_here = __private_to_binary_representation(n >> 1, print_here);
  (*print_here) = (n & 1) + '0';
  return print_here + 1;
}
```

## O primeiro dígito

Como estamos usando complemento de dois, o bit de sinal (o bit mais a esquerda, o mais significativo) é `0` para números positivos. A priori, a função que transforma o número para uma string binária funciona para números **positivos**. A transformação para número negativo se dá no próximo momento. Então, `__private_to_binary_representation` devolve a representação da magnitude do número, ignorando o bit de sinal. Para indicar que ele irá ignorar o bit de sinal, é passado para essa função a segunda posição de impressão, não a primeira. Também é passado o valor absoluto do número.

No retorna da chamada recursiva para o chamador original, obtemos a posição além da menos significativa, a posição adequada para se colocar o terminador nulo. Guardamos esse valor e então colocamos o valor terminador nulo nesse trecho:

```c
char* null_terminator_pos = __private_to_binary_representation(abs(n), print_here + 1, 0);

// garantindo o final da string
(*null_terminator_pos) = '\0';
```

Então, é impresso na primeira posição o número `'0'`, representando a magnitude do número passado em complemento de 2. Caso seja detectado que o número passado é negativo, rodamos o autômato para transformar a string.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado, ajudou muito :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void binario(int n){
    if(n!=1)
        binario(n/2);
    printf("%d", n%2);
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d%*c", &n);
    binario(n);
}
```

Minha solução é simples, mas deu certo para os números que eu testei. Espero que esteja certo e ter te ajudado. :x

Comment: Você imprimiu mas não obteve o valor. Sacou a diferença?

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado aposto que agora ta mais fácil pra ele entender, caso ele precise armazenar o valor é só ele fazer algumas alterações no código