# Quero fazer um conversor de decimal para binário sem usar itoa() ou vetores em C

Tags: c

O meu código dá certo até um certo ponto. Quando forneço valores acima de 1023 para num, o programa dá errado, abaixo de 1023 o programa funciona perfeitamente. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int bin = 0, num = 0, resp = 0, cont = 0;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    do
    {
        bin = (bin * 10) + (num % 2);
        num = num / 2;
        cont++;
    }
    while (num > 0);
    do
    {
        cont--;
        resp = (resp * 10) + (bin % 2);
        bin = (bin - (bin % 2)) / 10;
    }
    while (cont > 0);
    printf("%d", resp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você pode selecionar o código e pressionar `<ctrl> + k` para formatar o código adequadamente

Comment: Obrigado pela informação! Fiz as alterações já.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada nessa solução: [Decimal to Binary in C](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-convert-decimal-to-binary) que armazena o valor em uma string.. ou simplesmente printa na tela (a depender da sua necessidade)

Comment: Entendi. Queria usar apenas as operações básicas, mas vou considerar usar isso que colocou como solução. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Leitura interessante sobre a transformação para binário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267825/64969; supostamente essa resposta deveria ser bem básica e explicada, só necessitando entender de recursão.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que como está a guardar a representação binária num inteiro, rapidamente passa a capacidade de representação do mesmo e gera um *overflow*.

Observe o numero `1200` em binário:

```
10010110000
```

Veja o mesmo numero em inteiro, formatado visualmente para simplificar a leitura:

```
10,010,110,000
```

Que são 10 biliões, e claramente fora da gama de inteiros que vai até `2,147,483,647`.

Assim, a única coisa que precisa de fazer é alterar o tipo para um com mais representação, como o `unsigned long long`:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long bin = 0, num = 0, resp = 0, cont = 0;
    printf("digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%lld", &num); //tipo lld
    ...
    printf("%lld", resp); //tipo lld
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bdL5cV)

Alerto que no entanto, irá ter o mesmo problema se tentar converter números um pouco maiores, tal como `1000000`, pois a representação binária cresce demasiado rápido. Para contornar esse problema só mesmo guardando a representação numa `string`, que poderá ter o tamanho que quiser.

Comment: Acabei de testar. Funcionou direitinho. Pensei que o erro realmente podia ser por causa do overflow mesmo, mas não sabia como resolver. Muito obrigado mesmo! Para fazer com string, eu teria que usar vetores, né?

Comment: @Lucas Sim com `string` seria usando vetores

Comment: Ah sim, mas acho que o exercício proposto não pode ser feito com vetores, acho que o professor não permitiria. Mas mesmo assim, vou procurar como fazer essa solução com string. Novamente agradeço!