# Dúvida sobre recursividade em C

Tags: c, recursão

Estou aprendendo sobre recursividade, usando a linguagem C, e tenho que fazer o seguinte exercício:

> Projete uma função recursiva que receba um número inteiro n e calcule a soma dos dígitos de n.
>
> Por exemplo:
>
> para `n = 327`, o resultado é `12 = 3 + 2 + 7`.

Até tenho a resolução desse problema, que seria o seguinte código:

```
 int soma(int n){
 if(n%10 == n)
 return n;
 else
 return ((n % 10) + soma(n/10));
 }
```

Mas eu não entendi exatamente a lógica desse código, então agradeço quem puder me explicar =]

Comment: Já tentou fazer o teste de mesa?

Comment: [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878)

Comment: Dá para estudar bastante coisa de recursão aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267825/64969

Comment: Sim, mas ainda não entendi. Por exemplo, no if(327%10 == 327) eu teria 7 == 327, que não é verdadeiro, e assim vou para o else, que me retorna (327%10 [que é 7])) + soma(327/10) [que é 32,7). A partir desse momento não entendo exatamente o que acontece, pois pelo que entendi vou ter 39 (que seria 7+32,7, mas sem o decimal) e isso não deve estar certo, mas também não sei o jeito certo

Comment: Acho que entendi sua dúvida. No caso, em C e em quase todas as linguagens que eu conheço (exceção para [tag:python-3], ao dividir um inteiro por outro você obtém um novo inteiro. Então `327/10 ==> 32`, não `32,7` como nós aprendemos na aritmética dos números racionais. Bem vindo ao mundo da programação, onde você deve conhecer pelo menos 4 aritméticas distintas para realmente saber o que está fazendo: aritmética inteira, aritmética de ponto fixo, aritmética de ponto flutuante e aritmética de precisão arbitrária.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alterando somente a ordem de chamada, mas mantendo o mesmo sentido:

```
 return (soma(n/10) + (n % 10));
```

Cada vez que você irá chamar novamente a mesma função, você está passando o numero sem **o primeiro digito à direita**, o que acontece quando você realiza o `n/10` (repare que a divisão somente retorna a **parte inteira da divisão**). Esse processo é repetido até que `n%10 == n` (que no caso ocorre na **3° Chamada**). Quando a **condição de terminação** for encontrada na terceira chamada (ou seja se `n == 3` e `n%10 == 3`, então `n%10 == n`), a função começa a retornar o resto da divisão, ou seja, o **primeiro digito à direita** `n%10`, somado com o resto da função no qual à chamou. com isso você está somando todos os restos da divisão, ou, todos os dígitos do número.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se formos expandir em uma notação de recursividade, teríamos:

```
soma(327)
soma(32) + 7
soma(3) + 2 + 7
3 + 2 + 7
```

Ou em notação de arvore binária

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

**Código:**

```
#include <iostream>

int soma(int n){

 if(n%10 == n)
    return n;
 else
    return ((n % 10) + soma(n/10));

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%d\n", soma(327));
    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Explicação:**

Passo a passo da função `soma()` passando como parâmetro o valor `327`.

*Passo 1:*

```
int soma(int n){ // n= 327

 if(n%10 == n) // O resto da divisão de 327 por 10 é igual a 327? não, então vamos para o else..
    return n;
 else
    return ((n % 10) + soma(n/10)); 
    // Retorna o resto da divisão de 327 por 10 mais o retorno da função 
    // soma passando como parâmetro o resultado inteiro da divisão de 327 
    // por 10, ou seja, retorna 7 mais o retorno de soma(32).
}
```

*Passo 2:*

```
int soma(int n){ // n= 32

 if(n%10 == n) // O resto da divisão de 32 por 10 é igual a 32? não, então vamos para o else..
    return n;
 else
    return ((n % 10) + soma(n/10)); 
    // Retorna o resto da divisão de 32 por 10 mais o retorno da função 
    // soma passando como parâmetro o resultado inteiro da divisão de 32 
    // por 10, ou seja, retorna 2 mais o retorno de soma(3).
}
```

*Passo 3:*

```
int soma(int n){ // n= 3

 if(n%10 == n) // O resto da divisão de 3 por 10 é igual a 3? Sim!!
    return n; //Então retorna 3
 else
    return ((n % 10) + soma(n/10));
}
```

*Passo 4:*

```
 //Somar os valores que estam na pilha de memória 3+2+7
```

**Ilustração do método recursivo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta o que deseja é o seguinte (e usando recursividade):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somarDigitos(int valor)
{
    if (valor == 0)
        return 0;
    else 
        return (valor % 10) + somarDigitos(valor /= 10);
}


int main(void) {

    int soma = somarDigitos(372);
    printf("%d\n", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

O que a função faz é sempre pegar o último elemento do número através da função **mod(%)**, que pega o resultado da divisão por 10, e chama novamente a função dividindo o valor por 10, assim eliminando o último dígito, até chegar no último.